# Adding a new entry into a list of maps?

Tags: c++, maps

How do I add a new entry into this Phonebook program? This is what I have so far. Any tip or help would be great.

```
void enterNewEntry(std::map<std::string, std::list<PhoneEntry>*> & phoneInfo) {

    string  firstName;
    string  lastName;
    string  phoneNumStr;
    priority_t  priorityVal;

    enterFirstAndLastNames(firstName, lastName);
    enterPhoneNumStr(phoneNumStr);
    enterPriorityNum(priorityVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet doesn't provide info about PhoneEntry class, neither map key,
but still:

```
auto someList = new std::list<PhoneEntry>(); //creating empty list
someList->insert(phoneEntryObject);          //fill list with data
phoneInfo[someName] = someList;              //insert pair - key(someName) with mapped data(someList) into map container
```

don't forget to manually free memory, even when you want to just erase element

Would suggest you to take a look at std::multimap STL container.